# Pull-up not working on BCM 21?

Tags: gpio

I have discovered that BCM21 does not have pull-up resistor or at least not one controllable with the pigpio library. Is that some known fact which I have found hard to find? Or is there something working in the background preventing me to set the pull-ups?

For example how I see that BCM10 has pull-up capabilities:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs r 20
0
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs pud 20 u
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs r 20
1
```

And how BCM21 doesn't have:

```
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs r 21
0
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs pud 21 u
pi@testpi:~ $ pigs r 21
0
```

Using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the GPIO have internal pull-ups and pull-downs which can be enabled or disabled by software.

In addition GPIO 2/3 have external 1k8 pull-ups fitted.

In your case either GPIO 21 (pin 40) is damaged or it is connected to something which is pulling it low.

Check the mode of the GPIO with `pigs mg 21`.  If it is not set as an INPUT (returned pigs value 0) then the internal GPIO hardware may be setting the GPIO level.

Comment: My observations were for multiple RPi units. I now took a brand-new RPi out of the box and the same applies. There could be some Raspbian process or kernel configuration preventing the pull-ups working, but this is just a wild guess and I don't know how to track this down.

Comment: @user199309 Perhaps the auxiliary SPI is enabled, that uses GPIO 21. What does `pigs mg 21` report?

Comment: Yes, it was in mode 4 - SPI CLK. Manually setting mode to 0 made pull-ups work. Thank you for the tip.  If you could make this tip part of your reply, then I would upvote and set your reply as the answer.